# Create-react-app javascripts calling each others' functions not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, export, create-react-app

I am learning React.js with the create-react-app framework.

I need to use a readymade admin template which has javascript files calling other JS files' modules.

e.g. 
**In App.js I have:**

```
1. import $ from 'jquery'
2. import Layout from './css/layout.min.js'
3. import Navbar from './js/navbar.min.js'
```

**In navbar.min.js, I am getting an error:**

```
1. $ is not defined
2. Layout (a function of layout.min.js) is not defined
```

There are hundreds of such modules so manual import from each JS is not an option.

So far I've tried exporting $, Layout from App.js but no results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you install jQuery with npm? do you have a `export default` in `layout.min.js`?

Comment: I have installed jquery already in npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do ( id you didn't)

```
npm i jquery --save
```

And in your layout.min.js you should have `export default`.

Btw, maybe it should be `import Layout from './js/layout.min.js'?`

Comment: I have jquery installed in npm btw.